# Get footer to always be at the bottom - Using only CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get the footer to be, at the bottom of a page if there isn't enough content on a page?

I've tried some different CSS to achieve this but with no luck.
I can of course do it with JS, but i think CSS i a more smooth way if possible.

I think the problem is that my wrapper div (has the id="main") has float:none because i want to center it's content.

The page is http://runningaalborg.dk

Can someone help me??

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is commonly called **sticky footer**.

Have a look on this site, which use a pure CSS solution: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: Quoted from 'ryanfait.com' :: "I don't know web design. Can you help me with this?"

I charge for website assistance by the hour, and there's a minimum charge of 60 USD. However, there are plenty of CSS and web design forums on the internet where you can get free help. If you really want me to fix it, send me an email and we can discuss pricing.

Comment: @MilchePatern What indication do you have that anybody here wants to pay you to fix their code?

Comment: Quoted from 'ryanfait.com' .. witch is the writer of sticky-footer script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
html, body, #main {
    height: 100%;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in #lbBottomContainer

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```